# Keyword not supported: 'authentication' error while connecting to DB through Azure AD

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database through Azure AD from an Azure .NET Core application. I have also added Nuget packages `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`. But, I am getting this error:

> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'authentication'.
>
> at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
> at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms)

This is the code that I have written:

```
public static void testAADConnectionDbConnect(IConfiguration config)
{         
    string ConnectionString = @"Server=serverName; Authentication=Active Directory Service Principal; Encrypt=True; Database=databaseName; User Id=userId; Password=Password";          
    
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) 
    {
        conn.Open();
    }
}
```

Can I please get some help on it?

Thanks!

Comment: `Authentication=Active Directory Service Principal; ` <-- Where did you get this from?

Comment: @Dai: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#using-active-directory-password-authentication

Comment: What version of `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` are you using?

Comment: I think you need at least Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 2.0.0 for that. And it needs a service principal identity. What version are you referencing?

Comment: Note 1 says Authentication only works with Net Framework.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#setting-azure-active-directory-authentication  If you do not use Net Framework the connection string is completely different from the link you provided.

Comment: @jdweng That's not what the article says. It says **prior to version 2.0.0** of `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` it was .NET Framework-exclusive, but since 2.0.0 it should be supported on all runtimes (i.e. .NET 6, etc).

Answer (score 0):

- I was able to connect to the sql Database using the following process.
- First, I created a service principle using azure active directory. Just go to active directory and click on app registration and register an app.
- Also create a client secret by going in the `Certificates & secrets` tag and click on new client secret.

[image]

- Now while creating the SQL server in azure itself, we have to add `Authentication method` as `Use only Azure Active Directory (AzureAD) authentication` and then select the admin to the app registration done previously.

[image]

- Now make sure you are using the latest version of `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` in the code.

Complete code :

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string ConnectionString = @"Server=<ServerName>.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Service Principal; Encrypt=True; Database=<DatabaseName>; User Id=<Client/Application Id from app registation >; Password=<Client Secret created earlier >";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                if (conn.State== System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                { Console.WriteLine("Connection is Working "); }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image]